# Selecting Appropriate TVS Diode for protection against Load Dump

Tags: diodes, automotive, tvs

I am working on Bike Flashing lights. I have used 7805 as the regulator to supply +5V to the controller, also have 1N4007 in series at the input with capacitors.

I don't want to add any expensive components which may increase the cost. I was looking for TVS diode, but having the hard time to select the appropriate one for my application.

- Load Current is 100mA (Max)
- Voltage source is 12V battery

7805 Maximum Input Voltage is 30V.

Questions :

1. What should be the minimum breakdown voltage we should look for in a TVS?
2. What should the TVS maximum clamping voltage be in order to best protect the L7805 from Load Dump?

Supply Circuit :-

[image]

Below is the screenshot of some of the TVS Diode which is low cost.

[image]

Comment: Load dump overvoltage only occurs with a generator. If you are using a 12 v battery then you don't need overvoltage protection. What makes you think you will get voltage transients?

Comment: But the battery will be connected to the alternator in the motorcycle right? The electronic device will be connected to the battery and if battery is removed while it's charging, load dump will occur and I think it will effect the electronics as well.

Comment: so this is for a motor bike? then automotive protection may be overkill and you just need reverse battery protection and why / where is *1N4007 in series at the input with capacitors.*  No need for this

Comment: unless there is something else you aren't telling us... Vin max = 35V but 25V recommended If you are disconnecting battery during a 10A charge then the energy in the generator coil must be dumped into TVS whatever generator/alternator it is. you must specify

Comment: While the generator is connected to the battery you are not going to see large transients ....disconnect the battery and you could see load dump transients on the output of the generator. If you do this, then you might see 50-70 V transients. However if the battery is connected then it will itself shunt any transients.